# IIS searches for images in a path other than expected for an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, iis, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC5 application and I'm including the X-editable plugin for bootstrap in my project. When published, I see in Firebug that IIS is not able to find some images:

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - myserverip/myapp/img/clear.png"

But the css resides in myapp/Plugins/bootstrap3-editable/css/ bootstrap-editable.css

And the image is in myapp/Plugins/bootstrap3-editable/img/clear.png

The thing that I cannot understand is why it's looking for that image in the "myapp/img" path instead of "myapp/Plugins/bootstrap3-editable/img", where it really is, because the css that references the image instructs to simply go down one folder to search for that image:

> ... background: url('../img/clear.png')

So, in my poor logic, if the css is in "myapp/Plugins/bootstrap3-editable/css/", searching in  "../img" would be accomplished by going down to "myapp/Plugins/bootstrap3-editable/img".

By the way, if I create the folder /img directly at the root level and I put the image there, it works (of course).

Thanks for your help in advance,

Roger

Comment: You don't have the myapp/plugins/bootstrap3-editable/css virtually mapped as myapp/plugins/css?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I don't know what means that 'virtually mapping'. What should I do and where / how should I apply that ? Is it always needed to do in similar cases ?

Comment: Looking for more information, I've found that the issue is related to the fact that I'm using Bundles for css styles. When this is the case, you have to name your bundle (css) with a name that can be used as the relative path to the images. So in my case this has to be "~/Plugins/bootstrap3-editable/css/EstilsPluginsBootstrap". That way, the css can go down one directory and find the needed image. So if for every plugin I have to create different bundle names, I understand that using bundles under this circumstance is useless, and it's better to reference the css directly. Am I right ?